# Como introducir 2 datos en un mismo input de C

Tags: c

estoy aprendiendo C y encontre un ejercicio que pide que en un mismo input se introduzcan 2 enteros  y luego mostrar la suma y la resta de estos por lo que escribi el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    
    printf("Digite el valor de la variable a y b: ");
    scanf("%i,%i",&a,&b);
    printf("El valor es: %i, %i",a,b); //Esto lo puse para ver que es lo que reconoce el programa y asi fue como me di cuenta del error

    return 0;
}
```

y como salida me da:

```
$ ./"inout.exe" 
Digite el valor de la variable a y b1 2
El valor es: 1, 16
```

al parecer el problema lo estoy teniendo con el segundo valor pero no entiendo si puse lo mismo para el primer valor y me sale todo bien no se por que el segundo falla.

Comment: Quita la coma entre %i y %i.

Comment: Como indica Mateo, es por las comas que tienes en el scanf. Al introducir los dos números en la consola debes o bien poner la coma según indicas en scanf, o bien quitar la coma para poder poner los números por separado

Answer (score 0):

La función **scanf** recibe como primer parámetro una cadena de caracteres que define el formato que se va a utilizar para interpretar los datos introducidos.

El código que propones incluye una coma entre cada placeholder **%i**. Eso obliga al usuario a introducir dos números separados por coma.

Es conveniente eliminar esa coma en la llamada a **scanf**, de tal manera que se pueda aceptar un espacio, un tabulador o un retorno de carro entre los dos números que se van a introducir:

```
    scanf("%i%i",&a,&b);
```

Por otra parte, si se introducen dos números por teclado separados por una coma, el código propuesto funciona sin ninguna modificación.